# Write a query that shows record counts for different conditions on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query similar to below which shows record counts for several tables.

```
SELECT 'SomeTable' as tname, COUNT(*) as ttlRecords FROM SomeTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID
UNION
SELECT 'AnotherTable' as tname, COUNT(*) as ttlRecords FROM AnotherTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID
UNION
SELECT 'YetAnotherTable' as tname, COUNT(*) as ttlRecords FROM YetAnotherTable WHERE SubjectVersionID = @SubjectVersionID
```

The results look something like this...

```
tname            ttlRecords
SomeTable        25
AnotherTable     55
YetAnotherTable  120
```

Now, I'd like to modify this to further show some counts with a specific condition.  For this example, I have a RegionID that specifies whether the record is associated with the Canadian or US region.  So I'd like to show USRecordCount and CARecordCount on the same line with ttlRecordCount, like below...

```
tname            ttlRecords   USRecordCount   CARecordCount
SomeTable        25           10              15
AnotherTable     55           52              3
YetAnotherTable  120          100             20
```

I know I can do this using subqueries, like below, but it seems sloppy and probably slow.

```
SELECT 
  'SomeTable' as tname, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID) as ttlRecords,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID AND RegionTypeID = 1) as USRecordCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID AND RegionTypeID = 2) as CARecordCount
UNION
SELECT 
  'AnotherTable' as tname, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AnotherTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID) as ttlRecords,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AnotherTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID AND RegionTypeID = 1) as USRecordCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AnotherTable WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID AND RegionTypeID = 2) as CARecordCount
UNION
SELECT 
  'YetAnotherTable' as tname, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YetAnotherTable WHERE SubjectVersionID = @SubjectVersionID) as ttlRecords,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YetAnotherTable WHERE SubjectVersionID = @SubjectVersionID AND RegionTypeID = 1) as USRecordCount,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YetAnotherTable WHERE SubjectVersionID = @SubjectVersionID AND RegionTypeID = 2)as CARecordCount
```

My question is, is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using the pattern

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN <condition_1> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumCond1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN <condition_2> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumCond2,
    ....
    SUM(CASE WHEN <condition_N> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumCondN
FROM <table_name>
```

This will require iterating over all the records in the table exactly once. Each record will be evaluated by each aggregate expression (the `SUM`s) and will only increment the counts when the record matches the corresponding conditions.

Note that this may not be faster; it could be a lot slower! Consider the case where the table contains 1 billion records but only 1 record matches each of the conditions and there are indexes on each combination of columns used in the conditions. It would be far quicker in this scenario to find just those few records directly, using the indexes, than read over all 1 billion rows to find them. That is, to use the seaprate subquery approach as described in the question. This would only apply if you don't need to count the total number of rows, as is the case in the example below.

Here's your full example converted with an additional optimization, which may apply in your real work, moving any common conditions into the `WHERE` clause. Note the use of `COUNT(*)` to get the total number of rows concurrently.

```
SELECT
    'SomeTable' as tname,
    COUNT(*) as ttlRecords,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as USRecordCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CARecordCount
FROM SomeTable
WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'AnotherTable' as tname,
    COUNT(*) as ttlRecords,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as USRecordCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CARecordCount
FROM AnotherTable
WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'YetAnotherTable' as tname,
    COUNT(*) as ttlRecords,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as USRecordCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CARecordCount
FROM YetAnotherTable
WHERE SubjectVersionID = @SubjectVersionID
```

Comment: @Jim consider the note of caution in my updated answer. Although it's possible to do as you ask, it may not be advisable.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw it would probably be faster moving the "SubjectID = @SubjectID" to a where clause

Comment: @JoshJay Yes, this demonstrates the use of common conditions, and also highlights a situation where it is clearly better to use this pattern over lots of separate subqueries.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Thanks so much, I've implemented it exactly as your example and it works well and is plenty fast for the data I'm working with.  I'm working with maybe 100K rows per table, max.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw Cool, this might be unnecessary in this example, but what do you think about adding "ALL" to the "UNION" (i.e. "UNION ALL")? Might help performance a little.

Comment: @JoshJay I've added it but it wouldn't have any effect unless there were two tables with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement inside a SUM() statement

```
SUM(CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WhenAEqualsB
```

Updated with original info:

```
SELECT 
  'SomeTable' as tname, 
  COUNT(1) as ttlRecords,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as USRecordCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CARecordCount
From
    SomeTable
where
    SubjectID = @SubjectID
UNION
SELECT 
  'AnotherTable' as tname, 
  COUNT(1) as ttlRecords,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as USRecordCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CARecordCount
FROM
    AnotherTable
where
    SubjectID = @SubjectID
UNION
SELECT 
  'YetAnotherTable' as tname, 
  COUNT(1) as ttlRecords,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as USRecordCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN RegionTypeID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CARecordCount
FROM
    YetAnotherTable
where
    SubjectID = @SubjectID
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how that would solve the problem.  Can you explain, given my original example?

Comment: Actually, looking at other people's responses, I understand what you are saying now.

Comment: You were first, so I'll give a +1, but the other answer is much better so I'm accepting that one.  Thanks for answering!